# How to remove glued IC chip from PCB?

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering, repair

I used rework station hot air to 360 degrees Celsius for 3 minutes and the IC didn't come off! I hope I didn't damage it for prolonged heat exposure. Then I found out the IC is glued, I couldn't find any English resources online. Here's a picture of the glued IC

[image]

How can I remove it?

Comment: That obviously depends on what the glue is. Any ideas, maybe from scraping it with a scalpel...superglue, gel glue...?

Comment: if its not designed to release, the final option is to cut off all the leads and then pry it off - this could break the pcb, but if its already nonfunctional otherwise...

Comment: FWIW, from personal experiences, chances are good (but not certain) you didn't damage it with 3 minutes of air at 360 C, especially if you did it gradually and smoothly as you should always do. There's hope :)

Comment: You can try to cut the glue with thin steel wire (like pen springs are made off) put on under pins. Heat and acetone can help.

Comment: @TonyM probably thermal paste

Comment: More important not damage PCB. Cut the legs and remove them. After you can try remove the body. If it thermoconductive paste based on epoxy,  you can damage PCB even by using some chemicals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this:

Carefully unsolder each pin and lift it (don't break them). Usually you can get a tweezer or if you have a dental pic set you can carefully lift the pins up while putting heat on them. (If you are replacing the part and you don't care about the old one you could just cut each pin then unsolder).

Once all the pins are up you can try prying the chip from the board carefully using more force with each pry. At a certian point you need to be careful because you could pry up the solder mask or pad.

I suspect that this is a thermal sinking epoxy or it might just be thermal compound and not glue.

Comment: yeah, I believe it's a thermal paste. I lifted the pins as you said, but the ic still won't get pried. probably gonna damage something

Comment: try turning the IC, instead of lifting

Comment: It's not just glue, there's a soldered heat sink pad as well.  Trying to turn or lift the IC with the heat sink pad still fixed won't work. The only chance to remove it is heat and more heat... use a desoldering station underneath a fume hood.

Answer (score 3):

There is a chemical sold through several different channels that is intended for just this purpose. It is applied in very small quantity via an absorbent material, left in place and the PCB bagged and left for perhaps 30 minutes at room temperature, then the process is repeated one more more times until the adhesive softens sufficiently. Reportedly, it's primarily methylene chloride (an undeniably toxic - but very effective- old-school paint stripper chemical which is not quite banned yet in North America, but a bit harder to get ahold of than it once was).

Caveat- I have not tried it. I would sever the legs of the chip, remove them from the PCB, and try to break the remaining carcass of the IC free with a pliers and a twisting motion. I would also do it outdoors- you're unlikely to get a WHMIS MSDS with the product so excellent ventilation is a must.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment from Lundin above I checked the datasheet and confirmed that this part has a heat slug underneath:

[image: package image]

Package image from Infineons datasheet https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE8209-2SA-DS-v01_02-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624a0bf290014a0f5818836a1e

These are hard to remove without dumping a LOT of heat into the package and the ground/thermal plane beneath it.

So my advice to you is to get your board on top of a hot plate and use the hot air liberally until it separates.